# Upload to Windows Store

Tags: windows, windows-phone, tablet, tablet-pc

I have uploaded a Windows Phone app through https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows a few months back. Now I would like upload a Windows tablet version of the same application with the same name. Hence I uploaded the .appx in the same application as I did for .xap file. But the application is still not available for Windows tablets.Can any please guide me with this. Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a Windows 8 or 8.1 or 10 version of your app and then submit the app to the Store using the same app submission.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload .appxbundle instead of individual packages
But as I am understanding that you have published windows phone app and now you want Tab App.
So you need to contact Windows Store publishing Help Desk.